# echo sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't - why?

Tags: php

Form with download.php - does not work
Form with action with remove.php - works

Am I missing some little thing?

```
<table id="mytable1" width="80%"  class="text-center table table-striped table-bordered table-Responsive ">
    <thead>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>File Type</th>
    <th>File Size(KB)</th>
    <th>Remove</th>
    <th>Download</th>
    </thead>
    </tr>

<?php
    while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$item['file_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['file_type']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['file_size']."</td>";

    // this command does not work but the next echo works - why?
        echo "<td><form action='download.php' method='GET'><input name='filename' type='hidden'  value='".$item['file_name']."'/><button  class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type='submit' value='down'/><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></form></td>";

        echo "<td><form action='remove.php' method='GET'><input name='filename' type='hidden'  value='".$item['file_name']."'/><button  class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' type='submit' value='del'/><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-download'></span></form></td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }                   
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Im not really getting what you are trying to do. Because you are hiding the input fields, and button doesnt have any text? So you should not see anything?

Btw button should also be closed

Comment: i trying to echo the data from mysql along with two button on each row to that remove and download uploaded files

Comment: Just as a note - you use `glyphicon-trash` for the download and `glyphicon-download` for the trash.